# NAT Port Mapping from external IP to internal Web Server not working

Tags: networking, router, virtualbox, port-forwarding, nat

I am trying to setup an HTTP server using Virtual Box on my Win 10 Host.
The network is being set as a bridged network on the Guest using the ip 10.0.0.254.

Opening the browser with that IP is working fine so now Im trying to set up my Router to point my external IP to that server inside my netwrok.

I am using the "NAT Port Mapping" Feature of my router and I have configured the port 80 to point to my internal server's 80 port.

Something along the lines of this:

[image: Router Config]

The problem is that when I put my external IP onto the browser the web page that is shown is that of my router (10.0.0.1) instead of my actual web server (10.0.0.254).

I tried the whole thing with port 81, Configured the web server to listen to that port, tested it internally and worked, mapped the port on the router and made sure my windows firewall has a rule allowing public/private connections and I still get "connection refused" messages.

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong because logic tells me I am already mapping the port to my server.

Any pointers to what am I supposed to do or if there is something obvious that I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured that I was not using the correct Interface during the setup. As soon as I changed the Network Interface from "OTHER_R_0_35" (as shown in the picture) to the other available Interface "INTERNET_TR069_R_0_33" it started working right away.

So in general you have to specify the correct interface in some routers, I am using a Huawei HG532e. Probably this step is not needed on other Routers.